# Can anyone help me with these double Integrals using mathematica

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

$$ \int_0^6 \int_0^4 \frac{\sqrt{(1+x^2+y^2 )^2+4 ( x^2+y^2)}}{1+x^2+y^2}\, dy \, dx$$ And $$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-y}^y \frac{1}{(1+y^2)^2} \sqrt{(1+y^2)^4 + 4x^2(1+y^2)^2 + 4y^2(1+x^2)^2} \, dx \, dy$$

I don't have mathematica and we are expected to use it to find them

tahnsk

Comment: These are too much!

Comment: For the first one, I would try going to polar coordinates. The tricky thing will be getting the radial integration region right, which will depend on the angle.

Comment: I expected ppl to use a calculator, since wolfram cant do

Comment: If you are looking for a numerical answer, Mathematica can provide it using NIntegrate.

Comment: i dont have mathematica

Answer (score 1):

For the first one, converting to polar coordinates looks like an obvious choice, but that too turns out to be difficult. Anyway, in polar form:
\begin{align*}
  \int_{0}^{\arctan(2/3)} \int_{0}^{6/\cos\theta} \, f(r)\, r dr d\theta + \int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{4/\sin\theta} \, f(r)\, r dr d\theta
\end{align*}

where $$f(r)=\frac{\sqrt{(1+r^2)^2+4\, r^2}}{1+r^2}$$

After evaluating the inner integrals,

$\displaystyle
  \int_{0}^{\arctan(2/3)} \left( \mathrm{log}\left( \frac{2\,\sqrt{{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{4}+216\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+1296}+6\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+72}{{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}}\right) +
\mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}-9\cdot{2}^{{5}/{2}}}{2\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+72}\right) +\frac{\sqrt{{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{4}+216\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+1296}}{2\,{\mathrm{cos}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}}-\mathrm{log}\left( 8\right) -\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\, d\theta
$
$\displaystyle 
+ \int_{\arctan(2/3)}^{\pi/2} \, \left(\mathrm{log}\left( \frac{2\,\sqrt{{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{4}+96\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+256}+6\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+32}{{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}}\right) +\\ \mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{\sqrt{2}\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}-{2}^{{9}/{2}}}{2\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+32}\right) +\frac{\sqrt{{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{4}+96\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}+256}}{2\,{\mathrm{sin}\left( \theta\right) }^{2}}-\mathrm{log}\left( 8\right) -\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{1}{2} \right)\, d\theta
$

$\approx 27.43973001877135$

The numerical answer for the second one seems to be about $1.302$.